# wfile.write returning error when writing variable

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python script which I am trying to setup to output a json directory listing to a webpage. I'm making progress, but now I've run against a wall. By the way, I have almost no python experience. Here is my code:

```
if self.path.endswith("/"):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type',    'text/plain')
    self.end_headers()
    dirlist = os.listdir
    self.wfile.write(dirlist)
    return
```

and here is my error:

```
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\TiddlyWikis\Songs\Audio\server.p
y", line 18, in do_GET
    self.wfile.write(dirlist)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\socket.py", line 297, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' does not support the buffer interface
```

by the way, if you know of a python script that outputs json and everything, I'd be glad to just use it, since I'm nowhere near done with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I haven't the slightest idea what I was doing wrong, but I copied the list_directory function from http.py into my script and it works. Now I can work from here.

```
class MyHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def list_directory(self, path):
        #list_directory function code
```

Hopefully what is posted can help others.

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir(path)` Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by `path`. The list is in arbitrary order. It does not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.
http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir

`import json` and

```
if self.path.endswith("/"):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
    self.end_headers()
    dirlist = os.listdir('.')   # Change the path here
    self.wfile.write(json.dumps(dirlist))
    return
```

Comment: I get this error: `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`. What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Try this  
`self.wfile.write(buffer(json.dumps(dirlist)))`

Comment: @ArlenBeiler: try `self.wfile.write(json.dumps(dirlist).encode('utf8'))`. Of course, you can use any other encoding instead of *utf-8*

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you forgot to call listdir:

```
dirlist = os.listdir
```

This assign the *function* listdir to the name dirlist. That's not what you want, you want to get a list of files in a directory. You get that by calling the function listdir:

```
dirlist = os.listdir(path)
```

where path is the path to the directory you want to list.

Secondly, you are trying to write Unicode strings to a binary output. Don't construct the json data yourself, use the json library for that. http://docs.python.org/dev/library/json.html

Answer (score -1):

Try converting to a string explicitly first:

```
self.wfile.write(str(dirlist))
```

Then, with JSON:

```
self.wfile.write(json.dumps(dirlist))
```

You just need to format the dirlist "buffer" so that write() understands how to send it.

Comment: using `json.dumps` I get `TypeError: <built-in function listdir> is not JSON serializable`. `str` says `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

Comment: That's because you were doing `dirlist = os.listdir` instead of `dirlist = os.listdir()` as another answer pointed out.